# Differences on how XmlHttpRequest behaves with different browsers?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to see what are the gotchas in using XmlHttpWebRequest such that it works for Safari, Firefox and IE?

Answer (score 3):

probably the most obvious difference is how to get an XMLHttpRequest in the first place:

```
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Mozilla/Webkit/Opera
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
   xhr = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); // IE
} else {
   throw new Error('Ajax likely not supported');
}
```

that being said, i'd strongly look into an abstraction library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com). it makes things like ajax ridiculously easy:

```
$('#container').load('/ajax/resource');
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest also applies to IE7.  On IE6 the it would be better to use the ProgID MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0 to ensure a specific implementation returned (in some circumstances a version nuetral ProgID can returen a version 2.0 implementation instead).

Comment: There's also the difference between synchronous and asynchronous mode of operation. For some browsers, that implies an extra parameter in the call.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good article about all major [bugs found in XMLHttpRequest implementations](http://www.ilinsky.com/articles/XMLHttpRequest/) and a very light [implementation of a XMLHttpRequest wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/xmlhttprequest/) that works around these bugs while exposing exactly the same XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's somebody who got his hands dirty with that question:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3195000.htm

One general way to research these questions is to peek at the source code of a javascript library, like jQuery, since one of the functions of the library is to handle the differences.   Here's a snippet of jQuery that deals with XMLHttpRequest.  Note the comments about browser differences.

```
    // Create the request object; Microsoft failed to properly
    // implement the XMLHttpRequest in IE7, so we use the ActiveXObject when it is available
    var xhr = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Open the socket
    // Passing null username, generates a login popup on Opera (#2865)
    if( s.username )
        xhr.open(type, s.url, s.async, s.username, s.password);
    else
        xhr.open(type, s.url, s.async);

    // Need an extra try/catch for cross domain requests in Firefox 3
    try {
```

Comment: This is fine for a specific loading of HTML into a container but using Microsoft.XMLHTTP progid would be a mistake if you need consistent XML behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit of a cop-out answer, but this sort of thing will drive you insane if you use the built-in and inconsistent-across-browsers methods. Pick any javascript library and breathe a sigh of relief.